# Filter objects data in javascript using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

There is an object that includes other objects. The keys of this objects can be undefined, defined or empty. I am interested only in defined and not empty values of these keys. I will show examples:
data object

```
var d = {
    google: {
        email: 'zurb @gmail.com',
        name: 'k-pop Dorama',
        token: 'ya2XObIhOB63qjwlw',
        id: '11971093321'
    },
    twitter: {
        displayName: 'Smart as a Genius',
        id: '47252187865',
        name: 'Paul Peter',
        token: '47252ijoGYJ40bFAKvX'
    },
    facebook: {
        email: '',
        id: '1112961258784387',
        name: 'Tomash Khamlai',
        token: 'ERUTT8xK2oE7ZD'
    }
}
```

Fields that I want to collect:

```
var f = ["name", "email"];
```

Function that I tried:

```
function iterate(data, fields) {
    var response = Object.create({}, "");
    var property;
    for (property in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof data[property] === "object")
                iterate(data[property], fields);
            else {
                fields.forEach(function(element) {
                    if (property === element) {
                        if (data[property] !== "") {
                            if (!response[element]) {
                                response[element] = [];
                                response[element].push(data[property]);
                            } else {
                                response[element].push(data[property]);;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

iterate(d, f);
```

expectation:

```
 console.log(response);

{ name: ["k-pop Dorama", "Paul Peter", "Tomash Khamlai"], email: ["zurb@gmail.com"] }
```

Comment: It is even not accesible. I know about scope. But I do not understand where the word "return" should take place, because I understand only basics of recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isObj(obj, prop){
    return  typeof obj[prop] === "object"
}

function notContains(array, value){
   return !array.includes(value) ;
}

function getter(data, fields){
    var response = {}; 

    (function iterate(data, fields){
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(prop){
            if (isObj(data, prop)) iterate(data[prop], fields);
            else{
                fields.forEach(function (elem){
                    if(!response[elem]) response[elem] = [];
                    if(!!data[elem] && notContains(response[elem], data[elem])) response[elem].push(data[elem]);
                });
            }
        });
    })(data, fields);
return response;
}
```

Hey so I re-wrote your original code with a couple helper functions for readability. This should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I learned new method of ES6 [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
Your solution works very good!)